# List of arrays holding 2 objects each

Tags: c#, .net, syntax

What is the correct way to define a List holding arrays of objects of type T?

Each array holds only 2 objects.

Based on this definition:

*working*: `double[] balance = new double[10];`

I tried

*not working*: `List<T[]> arrList = new List<T[2]>();`

I need to build a list that looks like
([obj1,obj2] ... [objn,objm] ...)

Thank you

D.

Comment: Must you use an `array`? If you know that it will _always_ hold only two objects, you can use a `Tuple` or even a `Dictionary`? Even a list of some class objects?

Comment: I am discovering tuples at this very moment, your comment relates to the first answer given by Joel Coehoorn. So tuples seem to be the easiest way to go. Thank you

Comment: If you want a type that only holds 2 objects each, create a class that only holds 2 objects each. I do not understand the incredible antipathy beginners have to creating new classes.

Comment: @DourHighArch I am not looking for a new type, but you are right regarding the antipathy thing :)

Comment: Why you don't use multidimensional array .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to use a fixed-size for the arrays in the list. You have to do this:

```
List<T[]> arrList = new List<T[]>();
```

and then trust the outside code that each array added to the list will have exactly two items.

The only other options I can think of right now are using tuples:

```
List< (T,T) > arrList = new List< (T,T) >();
```

or creating your own class type for the List with an indexer property and exactly two members.

Comment: So I could access the data in this way: arrList[n].item1 / arrList[n].item2 ?